# How do I update a single field, using a variable as a field name?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to do something like

```
for field in field_list:
  my_table.field = new_value
```

Couldn't find any documentation on how to do the above with a variable.

Answer (score 5):

[`setattr(mytable, field, new_value)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)